# Make submenu list items inline using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I am trying to get the submenu list items to float inline and not stack as blocks. I would rather all the submenu items be flaoted underneath the menu so they take up less room but I can'seem to get anything to work.

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kustomdesigner/b1y5czf7/4/

```
<div id="jquery-accordion-menu" class="jquery-accordion-menu black">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Related Topics</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="/cloud-migration/">Cloud Migration</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-portfolio-management/">Application Portfolio Management</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-portfolio-management-tools/">Application Portfolio Management tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-portfolio-management-software/">Application Portfolio Management software</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-portfolio-management-solutions/">Application Portfolio Management solutions</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-migration/">Application Migration</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-modernization/">Application Modernization</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-portfolio/">Application Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cloud-readiness-assessment/">Cloud Readiness Assessment</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cloud-migration-tools/">Cloud Migration Tools</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cloud-readiness-b/">Cloud Readiness</a></li>
    <li><a href="/iaas-vs-paas-cloud-computing/">iaas vs paas</a></li>
    <li><a href="/what-is-paas/">What is paas?</a></li>
    <li><a href="/paas-vs-saas/">paas vs saas</a></li>
    <li><a href="/paas-definition-paas-examples-cloud-computing/">paas examples / pass definition</a></li>
    <li><a href="/iaas-paas-saas-cloud-computing-definitions-differences">iaas paas saas</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cloud-migration-strategy/">Cloud Migration Strategy</a></li>
    <li><a href="/cloud-migration-services/">Cloud Migration Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="/azure-migration/">Azure Migration</a></li>
    <li><a href="/migration-to-cloud/">Migration to Cloud</a></li>
    <li><a href="/application-migration-to-cloud/">Application Migration to Cloud</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- jquery-accordion-menu -->
```

Comment: Do you want them (subitems) to transition from _behind_ the menu to the bottom?

Comment: If you want them all to float inline then I wouldn't start with an accordion, you're very much working against its functionality.

Comment: rewrite CSS with flex (quick example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EvgKbL )  , best would be to clean the css file and jquery script of unwanted style/routine.

Comment: GCyrillus - I also thought about flex because I got flex-inline to work when I was looking at options.

Comment: Ok I tried your solution but it is still not working. Can you see if you can get it to work in the JSFiddle I posted?